# How can I merge three tables by id from 4th table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have one 'master' table and three other tables with some kind of details like below.

```
                +----------+
                |  TAB_A   |
                +----------+
               *|PK ID_A   |
 +----------+ / |FK ID_MAIN|
 |TableMain |/  | DATA_A   |
 ------------   ============
 |PK ID_MAIN|   +----------+   
 | Main_data|--*|  TAB_B   |
 |          |   +----------+
 ============   |PK ID_B   |
            |   |FK ID_MAIN|
            |   | DATA_B   |
            *   ============
       +-----------+
       | TAB_C     |
       +-----------+
       | PK ID_C   |
       | FK ID_MAIN| 
       | DATA_C    |
       =============
```

Example values:

```
        TableMain:            
    ID_MAIN   Main_data
       1        main1
       2        main2
       3        main3

       TAB_A           |          TAB_B          |           TAB_C
ID_A  ID_MAIN  DATA_A  | ID_B  ID_MAIN  DATA_B   |   ID_C  ID_MAIN  DATA_C
 1      2        A2    |  1      1       B3      |    1       3       C3
 2      1        A1    |  2      1       B3_1    |
 3      1        A1_1
 4      3        A3
 5      1        A1_2
```

and I want all details from TAB_A,TAB_B and TAB_C for each rekord from TableMain. 
The output should look like that

```
ID_MAIN  | Main_data | DATA_A | DATA_B | DATA_C |
-------------------------------------------------
1        |   main1   |        |  B3    |        |
         |   main1   |        |  B3_1  |        |
2        |   main2   |  A2    |        |        |
3        |   main3   |  A3    |        |   C3   |
```

Comment: +1, if only for the effort taken to write the question.

Comment: If you don't want the cartesian product implied by the foriegn key relationships, you will need to specify the logical rules for merging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to put values from different tables on the same row, you need to relate them to one another somehow. In the absence of an actual relationship, you probably have to make one up. One suggestion would be to assign row numbers per `ID_MAIN` in the three subordinate tables and use those numbers for matching.

If you are on SQL Server 2005 or later version, you could add row numbers using the [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) analytic function, and the entire query might look like this:

```
WITH A_ranked AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUM = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_MAIN ORDER BY ID_A)
  FROM TAB_A
),
B_ranked AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUM = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_MAIN ORDER BY ID_B)
  FROM TAB_B
),
C_ranked AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUM = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_MAIN ORDER BY ID_C)
  FROM TAB_C
)
SELECT
  ID_MAIN = COALESCE(a.ID_MAIN, b.ID_MAIN, c.ID_MAIN),
  m.Main_data,
  ROW_NUM = COALESCE(a.ROW_NUM, b.ROW_NUM, c.ROW_NUM),
  a.DATA_A,
  b.DATA_B,
  c.DATA_C
FROM
  A_ranked AS a
FULL JOIN
  B_ranked AS b ON b.ID_MAIN = a.ID_MAIN
               AND b.ROW_NUM = a.ROW_NUM
FULL JOIN
  C_ranked AS c ON c.ID_MAIN = COALESCE(a.ID_MAIN, b.ID_MAIN)
               AND c.ROW_NUM = COALESCE(a.ROW_NUM, b.ROW_NUM)
RIGHT JOIN
  TableMain AS m ON m.ID_MAIN = COALESCE(a.ID_MAIN, b.ID_MAIN, c.ID_MAIN)
;
```

You can take a look at a live demonstration of this query [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d687/1).

Comment: Thank You so much for fast feedback. It looks OK!. But I forgot to add one more 'condition'. The rows from TableMain shouldnt be duplicated. So if we need more rows, columns with ID_MAIN and MAIN_DATA should be blank.

Comment: Well, I believe that is a *presentation* issue. A query provides you with *data*. How the data are *displayed* is something that the calling application should decide. You could use the returned value of `ROW_NUM` for that: if it's 1, display `ID_MAIN` and `Main_data`, otherwise hide them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is a simple `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select TableMain.ID_MAIN, TableMain.Main_data, TAB_A.DATA_A, TAB_B.DATA_B, TAB_C.DATA_C
from TableMain
left join TAB_A on TAB_A.ID_MAIN=TableMain.ID_MAIN
left join TAB_B on TAB_B.ID_MAIN=TableMain.ID_MAIN
left join TAB_C on TAB_C.ID_MAIN=TableMain.ID_MAIN;
```

Documentation [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213228%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Comment: it is not left join. It would give me Cartesian product of DATA_A, DATA_B and DATA_C

Comment: Then what is the logic for placing a `TAB_A` row and a `TAB_B` row together, since they don't have any joins?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try this hope this helps you thanks

```
SELECT    dbo.TableMail.ID_MAIN, dbo.TableMail.Main_Data, 
          CASE WHEN DATA_A IS NULL  THEN '' ELSE DATA_A END AS DATA_A, 
          CASE WHEN DATA_B IS NULL  THEN '' ELSE DATA_B END AS DATA_B, 
          CASE WHEN DATA_C IS NULL THEN ''     ELSE  DATA_C END AS DATA_C

FROM      dbo.TableMail LEFT OUTER JOIN
          dbo.Table_C ON dbo.TableMain.ID_MAIN = dbo.Table_C.ID_MAIN LEFT OUTER   JOIN
          dbo.Table_A ON dbo.TableMain.ID_MAIN = dbo.Table_A.ID_MAIN LEFT OUTER  JOIN
          dbo.Table_B ON dbo.TableMain.ID_MAIN = dbo.Table_B.ID_MAIN

GROUP BY  dbo.TableMain.ID_MAIN, dbo.TableMain.Main_Data, CASE WHEN DATA_A IS NULL THEN '' ELSE DATA_A END, CASE WHEN DATA_B IS NULL 
           THEN '' ELSE DATA_B END, CASE WHEN DATA_C IS NULL THEN '' ELSE DATA_C  END
```

Comment: Thank You so much for fast feedback. It looks OK!. But I forgot to add one more 'condition'. The rows from TableMain shouldnt be duplicated. So if we need more rows, columns with ID_MAIN and MAIN_DATA should be blank. On my example above only ID_MAIN is blank. Is it hard to achieve?

Comment: Sorry it was false hope... it does not work. It is my fail because I gave wrong set of data that simply do not generate that problem.

Comment: I have updated Values, so now Your query generate Cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not just a simple trio of left joins? [Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/15642/2).

```
SELECT
            M.[ID_MAIN],
            M.[Main_data],
            A.[DATA_A],
            B.[DATA_B],
            C.[DATA_C]
    FROM
            [TableMain] M
        LEFT JOIN
            [TAB_A] A
                ON A.[ID_MAIN] = M.[ID_MAIN]
        LEFT JOIN
            [TAB_B] B
                ON B.[ID_MAIN] = M.[ID_MAIN]
        LEFT JOIN
            [TAB_C] C
                ON C.[ID_MAIN] = M.[ID_MAIN]
    ORDER BY
            M.[ID_MAIN] ASC
```

Comment: The same as previous soluttion. You will get Cartesian product

Comment: @user2839550, see my comment on the question, what do you want if you don't want the cartesian product? What are your merge rules?